# Модуль для распределения

Tags: python

Есть ли такой модуль (или функция) в Python, чтобы перемешать строку так, чтобы рядом не было повторяющихся символов?

Comment: а перемешивать-то зачем? Как это связано с "там не было повторяющихся символов" через "чтобы"? то ли две задачи - перемешать + не иметь повторений, то ли одна.

Comment: например 22221111 и он должен перемешать в 21212121

Comment: Ясно. Чтобы не было РЯДОМ повторяющихся. Не знаю такого модуля (может и есть, но не понимаю, для какой практической цели он нужен). Лучше исправить текст вопроса.

Comment: А функцию можно?(

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Algorithm to shuffle a list to minimise equal neighbours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881187)